# From bash script to bash script in infinite loop

Tags: bash, infinite-loop

A very simple example of the "just run once" version of my Script:

```
./myscript.sh var1 "var2 with spaces" var3
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 #output: var1
echo $2 #output: var2 with spaces
echo $3 #output: var3
```

Working as intended! 
Now I try to just start the script and enter the vars in a loop, because later I want to copy multiple datasets at once to the shell.

```
./myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash  
while true; do
  read var1 var2 var3
  #input: var1 "var2 with spaces" var3
  echo $var1 #output: var1
  echo $var2 #output: "var2
  echo $var3 #output: with spaces" var3
done
```

It seems read splits the input at the spaces, putting all thats left in the last var, right? Is there any better possibility to add vars in a loop? Or how do I get read to behave like I added the vars just behind the script?

And what is the English word for that kind of loop to execute one script in a loop while copying different vars to the shell? Can't google for samples if I don't know what it is called...

Comment: One small problem with your echo statements.  You forgot the "$" before the variable names (e.g. echo $var1)

Comment: Sry, just an errror in this sample. Fixed it

Comment: Look up the IFS variable.http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: IFS allows to split by other chars then spaces, like newline or comma. I could do comma seperated vars or something like that... Working but just a workaround...

Comment: @eye i think that using that work around is going to be the easiest way of doing this

Comment: There is no reason to use IFS when your intention is to treat stdin the way the shell parses arguments -- just have the shell parse each line as arguments as in my example below.

Comment: @BenGrimm There are tons of reasons not use eval though

Comment: @JID It is not appropriate in many cases, but in this context it's no more dangerous and fails no more often than if the user ran the program with equally bad arguments.

Comment: @BenGrimm I agree in this case it may fail no more often, but it is definitely more dangerous with bad input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads STDIN and parses those lines as arguments with shell quoting:

```
# Clean input of potentially dangerous characters. If your valid input
# is restrictive, this could instead strip everything that is invalid
# s/[^a-z0-9" ]//gi
sed -ue 's/[][(){}`;$]//g' | \
while read input; do
  if [ "x$input" = "x" ]; then exit; fi      
  eval "set -- $input"
  # check argument count
  if [ $(( $# % 3 )) -ne 0 ]; then 
     echo "Please enter 3 values at a time"
     continue;
  fi

  echo $1
  echo $2
  echo $3
done
```

`set -- $input` does all of the magic. See the Bash manual page for [set](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html).

```
--
    If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are   
    unset. Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the arguments, 
    even if some of them begin with a ‘-’.
```

Comment: Ok, no idea why, but works. Could you please explain what: set -- $input does? Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I suggested IFS as using eval is terrible practice. If the input contains a `;` it will fail, not only that whatever comes after will be executed. If for instance it contained `var1 "var2 with spaces" var3;rm -rf /*` then you may have a bit of trouble. BTW to any one reading don't try that.

Comment: All true -- I wouldn't normally blindly eval the input lines, but this is a minimum case. And of course, he's just using the REPL to save himself from running the command repeatedly.

Comment: Oh thats a big security issue. I will definitely need something  to prevent this from happening. Maybe just remove every ; before eval or something like this - there will be 3 people using this little programm, not just me. And btw - I'm a girl ^^

Comment: Sorry :) I added a simple input filter to the answer